# Maven flex,integrate several module,pop up flash error:VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.controls::List could not be found

Tags: apache-flex, maven, module, external

I have 4 flex project,3 are modules,1 is application.
compile these project with Flash Builder,integrate and run,is ok.
But when I compile these use maven script(Flex SDK merged into code).integrate and run,pop up error:
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.controls::List could not be found.

Somebody said because a library was loaded as external.
is that playerglobal.swc????
but after I change my pom.xml like this,seem like nothing changed.

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
          <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
          <type>rb.swc</type>
          <classifier>en_US</classifier>
          <scope>external</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Definitely not playerglobal.swc: that contains only ActionScript classes. mx List is located in `mx/mx.swc`.

Comment: It's not just the mx.controls.List class, I’ve  tried, if there is mx.controls.List, it's sure other class less. It seems like the Flex SDK framework was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add all Flex dependencies? Do your modules use Flex SDK with scope external? If so, does your application (which I assume, loads those modules) includes those classes?

When you use List in Module A and SDK is in scope external, then Module A expects that List will be available during runtime from Application. If you don't compile List into Application (as in, use List in Application) then Module A will complain about missing List class.

This is how Adobe decided to handle SWF optimizations :( Classes that are not used in Application or Module are not compiled into resulting SWF.

Comment: thanks,finally I am tired to merged sdk into code and use rsl,it is ok. I guess there maybe have two point 1: like you said. 2: do as you said, but I did not set a dependency between application and module, so after compile successful, integration the module to the application, conflict.

Comment: I can tell you that at work we have some tooling to support that, mainly during a Maven build all classes used in a module are added to a special, generated class. Later on shell application kind of loads this generated class which in turn means that the module will have all necessary classes in class path.